# asp.net forms modular Design

Tags: asp.net, forms, modular

I have a very big Asp.net Application and it should be developed as modules so any client can Purchase the modules he needs.
The idea is to have a host application that will do the authentication and basic functions and we want to drop asp.net application inside Modules folder and we have table in database contains the menus for the module then the host display the menu (the host and module use the same database) and render the page requested.

I'v searched a lot and found solutions for MVC using Areas but nothing for ASP.net Forms . I'v tried to use MEF but Couldn't succeed.
is there any way  to make asp.net forms render pages that exist in the file system but not included in the project.

please help me.